# Roundoff in generating a certain type of random image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

This is my first foray into javascript, and I'm trying to generate a random image with the following rule:

The colour of each pixel in the bitmap is randomly generated, row by row. The colour is chosen so as not to stray too far from the colour of the pixel to the left of it, and the result is averaged with the colour of the pixel above it.

I have found, however, that this averaging gradually inflates the rgb values and the pixels begin to hover very near to white.  I distilled a test case at http://geoburst.ca/eggs/testcase.html
and
http://geoburst.ca/eggs/testcase.js
where the meat of the code is as follows:

```
var i,dir,j,id=ctx.createImageData(cwidth,cheight);
for(i = 4; i < id.width*id.height*4;i+=4){
//alpha
id.data[i+3]=255;
for(j=0;j<3;j++){//for each colour r,g,b
    //I have to tell it to go darker more often, but then it still becomes lighter.
    //randomly choose the direction to move
    if(Math.random() <= 0.5){dir = -1;} else{ dir = 1;}
    //apply that move (I think the min max might be redundant)
    id.data[i+j]= Math.max(0, Math.min( 255, id.data[i+j-4] + 7*dir ) );
    //take the average of this value with the pixel above it
    //in the previous row if there is one.
    if(i>id.width*4) id.data[i+j] = (id.data[i+j]+id.data[i+j-id.width*4+4])/2
}
}
```

The array id.data[] is the r,g,b,alpha of the bitmap, row by row.
If you comment out the last line of the inner loop

```
    //if(i>id.width*4) id.data[i+j] = (id.data[i+j]+id.data[i+j-id.width*4+4])/2
```

the lightening problem disappears.  It can be partly fixed by chosing to darken a bit more often than lighten by increasing the 0.5, eg to 0.517

```
    if(Math.random() <= 0.517){dir = -1;} else{ dir = 1;}
```

But this sort of manual fix is not perfect.

Why does the image lighten towards the bottom, and how can I fix that in general?

(Aside: have you ever seen images generated this way before?  where?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas `imageData` is a typed array of integers, so all of your averages (of two integers, ending in .0 or .5) are being rounded to integers (adding either 0 or .5), causing the overall value to float upward over time.

I added "fuzz" to the average:

```
if(i>id.width*4) id.data[i+j] = (
    (id.data[i+j]+id.data[i+j-id.width*4+4])/2
    + Math.random() - .5
    )
```

and got what I think is the result you're looking for. Pretty!

Comment: aha!  Thank you for this.  I love clean simple answers.  So the integers are not floored?  I didn't think of this because I thought it would send the values down to 0 and not up to 255.